# Splitting files from a single folder to multiple sub folders in specific ratio using Python

Tags: python

I have bulk files in a directory. I need to split (divide) them into three folders randomly in the ratio 66:17:17. I normally do this manually but takes a lot of time.

ie

Source(directory): 100 files

Destination(directory) with Sub directories:

```
    Training:66 files(random)

    Validation:17 files(random)

    Testing:17 files(random)
```

I use a python script for random selection of 'n' number of files:

```
import shutil, random, os
dirpath = 'C:\Cyrb\Workspace\Sound_Training\Python_Scripts\Random_Selection_Tool\Source'
destDirectory = 'C:\Cyrb\Workspace\Sound_Training\Python_Scripts\Random_Selection_Tool\Destination'

filenames = random.sample(os.listdir(dirpath),24)
for fname in filenames:
    srcpath = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
    destPath = os.path.join(destDirectory, fname)
    shutil.move(srcpath, destPath)
```

I need a python script which does all these actions in a single run, which splits the files into subfolders randomly in ratio 66:17:17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that pretty, but it should work

```
import os
import random
import shutil


class Target:
    def __init__(self, target_path: str, ratio: int, number_of_source_files: int):
        self._target_path = target_path
        self._max = int(number_of_source_files / 100 * ratio)
        self._counter = 0

    @property
    def target_path(self):
        self._counter += 1
        return self._target_path

    def is_maxed_out(self):
        return True if self._counter >= self._max else False


def get_random_target(target_list):
    if len(target_list) > 0:
        return random.choice(target_list)
    else:
        return random.choice([validation, testing, training])


path_source = r'source_files\\'
source_file_list = os.listdir(path_source)
validation = Target(r'validation\\', 66, len(source_file_list))
testing = Target(r'testing\\', 17, len(source_file_list))
training = Target(r'training\\', 17, len(source_file_list))

targets = [validation, testing, training]
for source_file in source_file_list:
    target = get_random_target(targets)
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path_source, source_file), target.target_path)
    for target in targets:
        if target.is_maxed_out():
            targets.remove(target)
```

Comment: yes it worked!. . I just changed 'shutil.copy2' to 'shutil.move'. Now it's perfect

Comment: How can we make it work on a group of folders with files in it, such that inside each folder the splitting action happens?

Comment: Instead of using a list of files from path_source, you first read in a list of subdirectories. You then loop throught the directories and execute the same code for each of them. It does not really change much, all you do is create a double loop.

Comment: Can you edit it ? My knowledge level is not that strong..im just a budding developer

Answer (score 0):

This would be a version where you can put multiple directories in the `source_directories` folder. Each would be handled. But you might have to watch out to not overwrite files if they have the same name in mulitple subdirectories.

```
import os
import random
import shutil
import sys


class Target:
    def __init__(self, target_path: str, ratio: int, number_of_source_files: int):
        self._target_path = target_path
        self._max = int(number_of_source_files / 100 * ratio)
        self._counter = 0

    @property
    def target_path(self):
        self._counter += 1
        return self._target_path

    def is_maxed_out(self):
        return True if self._counter >= self._max else False


def get_random_target(target_list):
    if len(target_list) > 0:
        return random.choice(target_list)
    else:
        return random.choice([validation, testing, training])


directory_root = r'source_directories\\'
directories = os.walk(directory_root)
for directory in next(os.walk(directory_root))[1]:
    path_source = os.path.join(directory_root, directory)
    source_file_list = os.listdir(path_source)
    validation = Target(r'validation\\', 66, len(source_file_list))
    testing = Target(r'testing\\', 17, len(source_file_list))
    training = Target(r'training\\', 17, len(source_file_list))

    targets = [validation, testing, training]
    for source_file in source_file_list:
        target = get_random_target(targets)
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path_source, source_file), target.target_path)
        for target in targets:
            if target.is_maxed_out():
                targets.remove(target)
```